# Device collects data less than sampling rate sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, signal-processing, sampling, resampling

I am using a device to capture the ECG data at the sampling rate of 1000. For some seconds, the collected data is not even 500. Is it normal? If yes, do I need to calculate the new sampling rate from the offline data to calculate the correct r peaks? If so, what should my strategy be since I don't want to downsample my data?

Comment: You have varying sampling frequency? It is not normal. How do you collect your samples? There are ways of dealing with that (interpolation methods), but they are complicated and generally it is better to solve the root of the problem, instead of fixing results.

Comment: Yeah. The sampling rate was set to 1000, but I don't get the same number of data exactly.